# How to wrap around in hexadecimal multiplication?

Tags: ocaml, multiplication, word-wrap

Like I'm multiplying 0xff with like 0x02, the resulting hex is going to be greater than 0xff. How do I make it wrap around to the beginning?

Answer (score 4):

As @ivg pointed out, hexadecimal is just a notation for integers. It's not a whole new kind of number. That might help figure things out a little easier.

The answer to this particular question is to use the `mod` operator:

```
# 271 mod 256;;
- : int = 15
# 0x10f mod 0x100;;
- : int = 15
```

Comment: For printing in hex notation, use the `%x` or `%X` printf formats, e.g. `Printf.sprintf "0x%02x" 15` evaluates to the string `"0x0f"`.